# react error on componentDidMount -> Can only update a mounted or mounting component?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am new to React, so this is probably just a beginner's mistake.

In summary, it's throwing the error/warning mentioned and it is running fetch twice. It ends up with the correct final result though.

The set up is a page to show basic user profile information, with functionality to change profile to be added later.

Details:

- componentDidMount seems to be called once, as per the console.log output below
- fetch is called twice, for whatever reason. Both times it gets the correct info from remote
- this.setState({account.data.data[0]}) fails the first time around and throws the error. This is particularly strange as **it suggests the component is not mounted while it is called within componentDidMount**.
  The second time fetch and setState run it updates state correctly.

The exact error message:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

This is the main component:

```
class AccountTable extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        account:{},
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount');//outputs once
    fetch('/mon-compte-api', {
        method: 'get',
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('fetch'); // outputs twice 
        response.json().then((data) => {
            console.log('data', data);// correct output both times
            this.setState({account: data.data[0]}) // this throws the error
            console.log('state_account', this.state.account); 
// no output for this.state.account first time around. Correct output 2nd time 
        })       
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });      
}

render(){
    return (
        <table>
                <TableRow 
                   account={this.state.account} />
        </table>
    );      
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<AccountTable />,document.querySelector("#react_account"));
```

This is the child component:

```
const TableRow = (props) => {
if(Object.keys(props.account).length === 0){ //show something while awaiting fetch
    return (
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Loading.....</td></tr> // shows momentarily
        </tbody>
        );
}else{
        return ( // outputs correct info eventually
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Name</th><td>{props.account.name}</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Email</th><td>{props.account.email}</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        );  
}   
}
```

response info requested:

```
Status code: 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 11:53:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.8     mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9  Perl/v5.24.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.8
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Length: 600
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: I think the problem lies within the parent of AccountTable, can you post the code here?

Comment: Log full `response` status code and headers, it may have something to do with the way you authenticate. Maybe you receive a 401 at first call asking authentication, and then fetch makes a second call with your credentials. Couldn't find documentation for fetch, but it is well explained in request module : https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication

Comment: @GabrielBleu, thanks. I added response info above. It's 200 OK.

Comment: @LirenYeo thanks, but there is no parent. This is it.